# Mystery "guest" user for rabbitMQ

Tags: docker-compose, rabbitmq, django-celery

I know the "guest" user is the default for RabbitMQ, but I thought I'd configured everything to use different names.

My stack is Django / Celery / RabbitMQ, running in Docker.

First up, the error - I jst get loads of these - every few seconds:

```
rabbitmq_1       | 2020-07-29 08:28:00.775 [warning] <0.1234.0> HTTP access denied: user 'guest' - invalid credentials
rabbitmq_1       | 2020-07-29 08:28:05.775 [warning] <0.1240.0> HTTP access denied: user 'guest' - invalid credentials
rabbitmq_1       | 2020-07-29 08:28:10.776 [warning] <0.1246.0> HTTP access denied: user 'guest' - invalid credentials
rabbitmq_1       | 2020-07-29 08:28:15.776 [warning] <0.1252.0> HTTP access denied: user 'guest' - invalid credentials
```

**rabbitMQ Dockerfile**

```
FROM rabbitmq:management-alpine

ENV RABBITMQ_USER rabbit_user
ENV RABBITMQ_PASSWORD rabbit_user

ADD rabbitmq.conf /etc/rabbitmq/
ADD definitions.json /etc/rabbitmq/

RUN chown rabbitmq:rabbitmq /etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq.conf /etc/rabbitmq/definitions.json

CMD ["rabbitmq-server"]
```

**rabbitmq.conf**

```
management.load_definitions = /etc/rabbitmq/definitions.json
```

**definitions.json**

```
{
    "users": [
        {
            "name": "rabbit_user",
            "password": "rabbit_user",
            "tags": ""
        },
        {
            "name": "admin",
            "password": "admin",
            "tags": "administrator"
        }
    ],
    "vhosts": [
        {
            "name": "\/phoenix"
        }
    ],
    "permissions": [
        {
            "user": "rabbit_user",
            "vhost": "\/phoenix",
            "configure": ".*",
            "write": ".*",
            "read": ".*"
        }
    ],
    "parameters": [],
    "policies": [],
    "exchanges": [],
    "bindings": [],
    "queues": [
        {
            "name": "high_prio",
            "vhost": "\/phoenix",
            "durable": true,
            "auto_delete": false,
            "arguments": {}
        },
        {
            "name": "low_prio",
            "vhost": "\/phoenix",
            "durable": true,
            "auto_delete": false,
            "arguments": {}
        }
    ]
}
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
  rabbitmq:
    build: 
      context: ./rabbitmq
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    # image: rabbitmq:3-management-alpine
    ports:
      - "15672:15672"       # RabbitMQ management plugin
    environment:
      - RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER=rabbit_user
      - RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASS=rabbit_user
      - RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_VHOST=phoenix
    expose:
      - "5672"              # Port exposed between docker containers
    depends_on: 
      - db
      - cache

  celery_worker:
    <<: *django
    command: bash -c "celery -A phoenix.celery worker --loglevel=INFO -n worker1@%h"   
    environment:
      - DJANGO_SECRET_KEY=${DJANGO_SECRET_KEY}
      - EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD=${EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD}
      - DJANGO_SETTINGS=${DJANGO_SETTINGS}
      # HC the rabbit user. Not secure obvs, but OK for PoC.
      - RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER=rabbit_user
      - RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASS=rabbit_user
    ports: []
    links:
      - rabbitmq
      - cache
    depends_on: 
      - db
      - cache
      - rabbitmq
```

**settings.py**

```
CELERY_BROKER_URL = "amqp://rabbit_user:rabbit_user@rabbitmq:5672/phoenix"
CELERY_BROKER_VHOST = "phoenix"
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = "django-db"
CELERY_CACHE_BACKEND = "default"
CELERY_TIME_ZONE = TIME_ZONE
```

I had it all working before when I just pulled the default rabbitMQ container in the docker-compose yaml file. Now I've created a specific Dockerfile for rabbitMQ, and setup `rabbit_user` and the vhost "phoenix". It all seems to be working - tasks are run, I see the message stats in the rabbit console, but I'm suffering these random "guest" login attempts. The word "guest" appears nowhere in my codebase, so somewhere RabbitMQ is using the default not "rabbit_user", but I can't see where.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather typical that I solve this by "fixing" something else ..

I noticed in my RMQ panel that the low_prio and high_prio queues had vhost "/phoenix", while the celery workers had vhost "phoenix" (I'd thought the RMQ config required the leading slash from my reading). I amended this so that all queues were allocated to "phoenix", and the mystery guest login disappeared.

I can only assume that since Celery was configured for the vhost "phoenix", that "/phoenix" was treated as s different vhost, with no users assigned to it, so RabbitMQ tried to use the "guest" default.

Not entirely sure why things were connecting to it - I'd sent nothing to those queues yet - but in case somebody else has this issue, this is what solved it for me.